# Set AWS load balancer to pass on partial page as it is generated

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, flush

> Question:

How can I configure the AWS LB to pass content to the browser in smaller chunks and not wait 'till the page is fully rendered?

> Back Story:

I have a php page that has to do some slow api queries.  I've designed the page to start sending the generated content before the slow part, so it can be displayed in the browser asap.  (using php's flush statement)

This works sweet when developing locally but when I put it in prod, I get none of the benefit of the partial page being sent early.  I have to wait and then the whole page shows up.

The prod server is behind an AWS Load Balancer.  I'm figuring the LB is waiting for the full request to finish before sending any data back to the browser.

IDK what keywords to be searching for so my google searching is coming up empty.  Thanks for the help.

> More Details:

It is actually 30 api calls totaling 15 seconds of page load time, I don't have control over improving the 3rd party api.  Seeing the data fill in as the user waits really helps the experience on the page.

To make the partial loading possible, the page is loading inside an iframe of the parent page.  Its mimetype is text/html and the contents are individual script blocks that set data on the parent page.  Since each script block is closed out before flushed, the browser will run the scripts as they arrive.

The total size of the page is pretty small as each script is only a couple lines long.

> Another use case

Based on comment feedback, I should just break apart my AJAX call to 30 separate requests.  To help focus on the original question (of "Do I really lose support for partial transfer if I use AWS LB?"), here's another example case.

Let's say I have a page that has 50ms of DB queries and logic in order to render the body of the page, but the head section of the page is known right away.  I could put a flush; command after the head tag and would expect that partial page to be sent so the browser can process the head 50ms sooner.  (head sections often have one or more external css resources, and the browser could get those requests sent off)

Comment: You could accomplish this pretty easily using AJAX on the client side. Load a much smaller page that has some javascript in it. The javascript will trigger each block and when the results return, have a callback to populate the result back into the page. Google around for AJAX to get a feel for how this could work for you.

Comment: ELB is probably not optimized for this unusual behavior pattern.  You might inspect the payload on both sides.  I *think* php will automatically do `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` if you `flush` without having set a `Content-Length:` but I expect ELB might re-chunk the chunks (easily confirmed with a sniffer on both server and browser sides), and the only workaround might be TCP mode instead of HTTP, which is probably not going to be what you want.

Comment: @Chris  True, turning this one request into 30 requests on the client side would be a work around that would solve it (simple AJAX too, no iframe business).  One request to my server seems cleaner and I had already done the work of building it this way, so I'm asking this question specifically about the AWS LB to see if there's a LB setting or http header I should try.  This is my first project behind a LB and am interested to spend the time to learn about it instead of work around it.

Comment: As @Michael mentioned, you could try setting the ```Transfer-Encoding: chunked``` but the ELB isn't really designed to work this way. If you don't like the idea of multiple requests, you could also try setting up an Nginx load balancer instead of an ELB. This is a lot more work on your part, and in my opinion not really worth the trouble. Standard practice is to split the page into smaller chunks and load dynamically, so I hope you at least consider it :)

Comment: @Michael  php is automatically adding Transfer-Encoding: chunked  That header is not found by the time the LB passes it on.  I'll see if I can find any other differences.  Ah, the LB has a TCP mode, thanks, I did some reading up on that.  I'm using the SSL features of the LB in HTTPS mode, so would not be able to move away from that.

Comment: (I've updated the question with another use case)

Comment: You can still use SSL in TCP mode.